# All files committed to cvs repo when only half are actually listed via commands

Tags: cvs

I have a lot of files inside a lot of directories that I'm committing to cvs. Here are the steps I take-

1. cvs add directories
2. cvs add files
3. check the cvs repo - I see the directories but no files since the files have to be committed
4. I then submit the files to be committed as an LSF batch
5. bsub cvs commit -m "" file
6. I might have 100 jobs running and 900 jobs in queue
7. somebody complains, so I kill my jobs in queue (not the running ones)
8. I do a checkout of the module and everything is there instead of just the ones that committed via LSF

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `bsub` command does, but you do not need to commit every file individually. If you do `cvs commit` from a particular directory, it will commit all files in the current directory and all subdirectories. It's possible that everything was committed in the first job and all the other jobs weren't doing anything. But I don't know that for definite without knowing how `bsub` works.

Comment: Essentially what I was doing with bsub was sending a cvs commit myfile command to many different computers to try to commit in parallel.
What you said seems to be what is happening, but is that expected behavior? Is cvs just ignoring my file argument then? On windows I can selectively commit files, even other files have been added.

Comment: Given the way cvs works, trying to commit every file in parallel would have no benefit. cvs doesn't ignore the file name. If you try to carry out an action on a file which doesn't exist, it will complain. eg. `cvs commit x` gives `cvs commit: nothing known about x`.